# Action Bar's onClick listener for the Home button

Tags: android, android-intent, actionbarsherlock, onitemclicklistener

How can I implement a custom `onClickListener` for the Home button of the Action Bar?

I already did a `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` and now I want to redirect the user to a certain activity in case the Home button is clicked.

I tried with:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.setClass(BestemmingActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

but it never enters in the `onMenuItemClick`.

Basically, it's done just like in [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Up) but still it doesn't enter in the listener.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed: no need to use a `setOnMenuItemClickListener`.
Just pressing the button, it creates and launches the activity through the intent.

Thanks a lot everybody for your help!

Comment: Right, the action bar takes care of menu listeners and calls `onOptionsItemSelected()` automatically. No need to install manually (that can actually break things).

Answer (score 124):

if anyone else need the solution

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();  return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Worked for me with `return true;`

Comment: Put a `return true;` at the end of the `if` block, then it's correct

Comment: This approach is not working for Home/Back button with arrow icon.

Answer (score 111):

I use the [actionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/index.html),
after we set `supportActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);`
we can override the onMenuItemSelected method:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    switch (itemId) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        toggle();

        // Toast.makeText(this, "home pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;

    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work me me. Cannot override onMenuItemSelected as its final.

Comment: With android annotations just use @OptionsItem(android.R.id.home) public void yourMethod() { }

Answer (score 24):

if we use the system given action bar following code works fine

```
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    switch (itemId) {
    case android.R.id.home:
      //do your action here.
        break;

    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

answers in half part of what is happening. if `onOptionsItemSelected` not control `homeAsUp` button when parent activity sets in manifest.xml system goes to parent activity. use like this in activity tag:

```
<activity ... >
<meta-data
android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
android:value="com.activities.MainActivity" /> 
</activity>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to explicitly enable the home action if running on ICS. From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home):

> Note: If you're using the icon to navigate to the home activity, beware that
>   beginning   with Android 4.0 (API level 14), you must
>   explicitly enable the icon as an action item by  calling
>   setHomeButtonEnabled(true) (in previous versions, the icon was enabled
>   as an action  item by default).

Comment: I already did a `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` and a `getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);`

Answer (score 2):

Best way to customize Action bar onClickListener is onSupportNavigateUp()

This code will be helpful [link for helping code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304483/proper-way-to-handle-action-bar-up-button/37692750#37692750)

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
android:parentActivityName=".NameOfParentActivity"
```

to the activity (in AndroidManifest.xml) that displays the settings.

Answer (score -4):

you should to delete your the Override onOptionsItemSelected and replate your onCreateOptionsMenu with this code

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_action_bar_finish_order_stop, menu);
        menu.getItem(0).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new FinishOrderStopListener(this, getApplication(), selectedChild));
        return true;

    }
```

Comment: Please add some explanations to help people to understand and go (back?) reading stackoverflow's policies about answer with only code.