# when i open a link in android webview in app browser how can i put close button on top left

Tags: java, android, webview, inappbrowser

Please Refer this example http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/

In the above link example when we clink on button it redirects to google home page. Google page opening in webview. On the top i want to put close button. So when i click close button it has to go to previous back page. Please see below image for example.

[image: A screen shot]

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.hide();
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView viewx, String urlx) {
                viewx.loadUrl(urlx);
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Please click on link for image.

Comment: You have tagged this as inappbrowser (which is usually taken to mean the customized version of the webview that's found in Cordova) and also as Webview. Which one are you using? Please update your question with that information and also remove one or the other tags.

Comment: You need to create a header on top of your webview. You can use a simple linearlayout with a button in it for this purpose.

Comment: I have modified my post. Please check it once and help me. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this site. Could you please explain clearly.

Comment: Please help me... @Rahul Tiwari

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines from your code:

```
 ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
 bar.hide();
```

Now replace your home button on action bar with an 'X' icon and override its action like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16150755/1529129):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
          finish();
    }
    return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem));
}
```