# What is diffrence between back button and setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled in an activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have two activtiy. When a boolean variable in activity 1 is true then the UI in activity 2 should be update  (activity 2 is with fragment). When I back to activity 2 with (setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled) it works correctly but with back button it does not work. What is the difference between this ways and how I can solve this. I try update the activity 2 with this code but it does not work:

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
         //update();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Home Button is not meant to behave like the Back Button. See [this reference](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html). The Home or "Up" Button should take the user up within the view hierarchy (i.e. if you have a number of multiple choice fragments, don't go back through each of them, but back to the activity that started the first fragment)

Each activity should specify what it's parent activity is in order to properly use this functionality. You can do this through the manifest, or by overriding onOptionsItemSelected() as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150205/android-action-bar-home-button)

In terms of why your activity 2 may be updating when using the "Up" button but not the back button, this could be because both handle the back stack in a different way. Back will take you to the last thing on the stack and resume it, assuming you don't haven't tagged the activity with a launchmode that alters this behavior. [Here's more info on the back stack.](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html) If you haven't designated your Activity 2 as "singletop" then when you use the "Up" Button, a new instance of that parent activity is created. [See here.](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) This may means that the information is updating after using the home button because it's creating a new instance of the activity, while for the back button - you are not creating a new instance but resuming a previous instance... make sure you implement an onResume() function to properly handle this and update the information.