# App home button not preserving data

Tags: android, listview, navigation

On my apps home page I have an option to add items to a `ListView` using `adapter.add(string)`. I also have another `Activity` that my app goes to using `startActivity(intent)`. When I am in that second `Activity` and I press the back button all of the data that was added to the list is still there, however when I press the icon at the top left all the data is gone. Is there a way to make it so that the button for the icon preserves the data in my list. I think I should note that I don't want the data to be preserved when the app is closed, only when navigating through the open app.

This is my current method that handles the home button action:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution would be to call `onBackPressed()` instead of `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)`. This, however, isn't recommended and you should try to implement proper navigation logic. Take a look at the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906116/which-one-to-use-navutils-navigateupfromsametask-vs-onbackpressed) question as well as [these](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1874864) tips.

Comment: I followed the first link and found a solution there. Thank you!