# How to go back from 3rd activity to second activity by back button?

Tags: android, android-activity

I just started android programming and I created 3 activities.A button in each activity will open another.I can navigate from my 2nd activity back to my first but I can't navigate from my third activity back to my second.Here's what I tried but the app crashes when I click on the back button. I guess it's trying to jump from the third activity to the second. If it helps my second activity's java file is called **CountryDetails.java**

```
 public class WikiPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_activity_wikipedia_details);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your manifest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Remove **`NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);`**

You should use [**`onBackPressed()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onbackpressed) only.

> Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back
>   key. The default implementation simply finishes the current activity,
>   but you can override this to do whatever you want.

```
case android.R.id.home:
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I was wondering what's the difference between navigateUpFromSameTask and onBackPressed

Comment: @SookLim Read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils#navigateupfromsametask

Comment: @SookLim, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906116/which-one-to-use-navutils-navigateupfromsametask-vs-onbackpressed answer in this link will help you understand the difference between the two.

Comment: @parekhkruti26 indeed. Thanks for info.

Answer (score 4):

Simply call `onBackPressed()` instead of `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)`

Answer (score 0):

Use ***onBackPressed()*** instead of ***NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)*** for activity backstake manage