# On Up back button click navigate to particular fragment from activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to navigate from an **second activity** to specific fragment  in **Bottom Navigation View** in **first activity** by using Up(<-) back Button.
i have tried code

```
         val actionBar = supportActionBar
         actionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
```

but,while placing parent activity in Manifest File,it wont show the fragment which is required by me.it is going to Home fragment in the 1st activity.

This is my fragment code in First Activity

```
      btm = findViewById(R.id.navigation) as BottomNavigationView
         btm.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        var selectedFragment: Fragment? = null
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_home ->
                selectedFragment = ReferFragment.newInstance()
            R.id.navigation_dashboard ->
                selectedFragment = AccountFragment.newInstance()
            R.id.navigation_notifications ->
                selectedFragment = ProfileFragment.newInstance()
        }

        var ft: FragmentTransaction = 
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment)
        ft.commit()
        true
    }
    var ft: FragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, ReferFragment.newInstance())
    ft.commit()
```

i want to goto 3rd fragment while clicking on UP backButton in second activity.
THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

> On Clicking Up back button from Second Activity pass an Intent Flag.

like below

```
Intent mIntent=new Intent(SecondActivity.this,FirstActivity.class);
mIntent.putExtra("IS_FROM_SECOND",true);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

Now in First Activity in `onCreate()`

check intent

```
boolean isFromSecond=getIntent().hasExtra("IS_FROM_SECOND");
```

> Note:- Do not use key "IS_FROM_SECOND" in any other intent.

so if it is the case then
 check

```
if(isFromSecond)
  var ft: FragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, 3rdFragment.newInstance())
    ft.commit()
}
```

Comment: hello sir, i am new to android development.i have used                                                                            
          val actionBar = supportActionBar
         actionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) for backButton.How can i assign above code to that button.please help me with this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079718/action-bars-onclick-listener-for-the-home-button

Comment: the above link is related to activity. my issue is when those activity contains three fragments and backButton redirection will be to specific Fragment.The Above Link Didn't help me sir.